# Computing number of sequences

Tags: algorithm, combinatorics

I saw the following problem that I was unable to solve. What kind of algorithm will solve it?

We have been given a positive integer n. Let A be the set of all possible strings of length n where characters are from the set {1,2,3,4,5,6}, i.e. the results of dice thrown n times. How many elements of A contains at least one of the following strings as a substring:

```
1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6
1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3
4, 4, 5, 5, 6, 6
1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2
3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4
5, 5, 5, 6, 6, 6
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1
2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2
3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3
4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4
5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5
6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6
```

I was wondering some kind of recursive approach but I got only mess when I tried to solve the problem.

Comment: I assume that `n >= 6`, since your required substrings have a length of 6.

Comment: You can assume that or it is not too hard to put `if n<6 return 0;` in your code.

Comment: Can substrings be repeated? I mean, should `1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6` be counted as a separate valid string when compared to, say, `1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 1, 2, 1, 2, 3, 5`? EDIT: Turns out that this doesn't matter for the solution.

Comment: They can be repeated. As those two examples are different but contains both the substring `1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6`, those two strings are two different valid strings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest reading up on the [Aho-Corasick algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aho%E2%80%93Corasick_algorithm).  This constructs a finite state machine based on a set of strings. (If your list of strings is fixed, you could even do this by hand.)

Once you have a finite state machine (with around 70 states), you should add an extra absorbing state to mark when any of the strings has been detected.

Now you problem is reduced to finding how many of the 6**n strings end up in the absorbing state after being pushed through the state machine.

You can do this by expressing the state machine as a matrix .  Entry M[i,j] tells the number of ways of getting to state i from state j when one letter is added.

Finally you compute the matrix raised to the power n applied to an input vector that is all zeros except for a 1 in the position corresponding to the initial state.  The number in the absorbing state position will tell you the total number of strings.

(You can use the standard [matrix exponentiation algorithm](http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/matrix-exponentiation/) to generate this answer in O(logn) time.)

Answer (score 0):

What's wrong with your recursive approach, can you elaborate on that, anyway this can be solved using a recursive approach in O(6^n), but can be optimized using dp, using the fact that you only need to track the last 6 elements, so it can be done in O ( 6 * 2^6 * n) with dp.

```
rec (String cur, int step) {
   if(step == n) return 0;
   int ans = 0;
   for(char c in { '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6' } {
      if(cur.length < 6) cur += c
      else {
         shift(cur,1) // shift the string to the left by 1 step
         cur[5] = c // add the new element to the end of the string
      }
      if(cur in list) ans += 1 + rec(cur, step+1) // list described in the question
      else ans += rec(cur, step+1)
   }
   return ans;
}
```

Comment: I was thinking that I have 6^5=7776 cases that the five last throws can be so making the recursion to handle all cases might be difficult.

Comment: I didn't really understand your comment, 6^5 cases do you mean 6^n? and way recursion to handle all cases might be difficult? I think it's pretty simple, the code is above explain it.

Comment: I meant 6^5. To find out how many string of length n contains suitable string I have to find out the number of strings of length n-1 does not contain one of those 12 strings but have correct five digits at the end so that concatenating the last character to the end gives a string that has a suitable substring at the end.

Comment: There seems to be an method in https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1353743/how-many-patterns-there-are-in-a-sequence-of-dice-throws